# Why is it Moon Prism Power, instead of Moon Power, which would follow the pattern of the other initial transformations?

Tags: sailor-moon

Why is Usagi's initial transformation called **Moon Prism Power**, instead of **Moon Power**, which would follow the pattern of the other initial Sailor Senshi transformations, such as:

- **Mars Power**
- **Mercury Power**
- **Jupiter Power**
- **Venus Power**